# Need to calculate the duplicate items in a column and separate the items having some conditions on it in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to ORACLE SQL world. I am trying to figure out a way to calculate something as below.

Let's say that I have following data available in a table 'A'.
Status is produced by different logic, just for the sake of simplicity I am taking sample Status.

```
Name               Status
---------------------------
John                 N
John                 Y
Smith                N
Karrie               Y
Walter               N
Smith                Y
Walter               N
John                 N
Walter               N
Karrie               Y
```

Now, I want to output something as below :

```
Name                Status               Flag
-----------------------------------------------
John                 N                     S
John                 Y                     S
John                 N                     S
Smith                N                     S
Smith                Y                     S
Karrie               Y                     Y
Karrie               Y                     Y
Walter               N                     N
Walter               N                     N
Walter               N                     N
```

This is just a sample data and a sample output.

Basically, Let us take an example of John:

- If There are 3 John's available, having multiple 'N's and at least one 'Y', then I want the flag to be 'S'.
- If There are 3 John's available, having multiple 'N's and **No** 'Y', then I want the flag to be 'N'.
- If there are 3 John's available, having multiple 'Y's and **No** 'N', then I want the flag to be 'Y'.

I have tried this by adding extra column as count*, which partitions the table by **Name**, and counts all the names in it.
Which eventually would tell me "How many 'Y' and 'N' could be there !".

But, even if i count all those Names, I am unable to separate out 'Y' and 'N'.

Not sure how can I achieve this through pure SQL.

I know that

```
If COUNT('N') = COUNT('John') then 
flag = 'N' 
else if COUNT('N') < COUNT('John') then 
flag = 'S' 
else flag = 'Y'.
```

This is what i tried:

```
SELECT a.NAME
       , a.status
       , COUNT(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) COUNT 
FROM A a;
```

I am stuck after this.

Could you please help me out ?

This is my expected output:

```
Name                Status               Flag

-----------------------------------------------
John                 N                     S
John                 Y                     S
John                 N                     S
Smith                N                     S
Smith                Y                     S
Karrie               Y                     Y
Karrie               Y                     Y
Walter               N                     N
Walter               N                     N
Walter               N                     N
```

Comment: *If There are 3 John's available* what if there are 2 or 1. The conditions do not apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the rule is just simply:

- if all statuses are the same then show the status
- else show an S

So `COUNT DISTINCT` or compare `MIN` and `MAX` to determine whether there is only one status for a name.

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.status,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT status) OVER (PARTITION BY name) = 1
       THEN status
       ELSE 'S'
  END AS flag
FROM a;
```

or

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  a.status,
  CASE WHEN MIN(status) OVER (PARTITION BY name) = MAX(status) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
       THEN status
       ELSE 'S'
  END AS flag
FROM a;
```

If `status` can be NULL, I'd recommend `DECODE` instead of `CASE WHEN`, because `CASE WHEN` would become less readable.

Comment: Simpler: in the first branch of the **case** expression, **then status** will work just as well.

Comment: @mathguy: Well spotted. Thank you very much. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the different statuses for each name with conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
  sum(case status when 'N' then 1 else 0 end) ncounter,
  sum(case status when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) ycounter
from tablename
group by name
```

and then join this query to the table:

```
select t.*,
  case 
    when c.ncounter = 0 then 'Y'
    when c.ycounter = 0 then 'N'
    else 'S' 
  end Flag
from tablename t inner join (
  select name,
    sum(case status when 'N' then 1 else 0 end) ncounter,
    sum(case status when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) ycounter
  from tablename
  group by name
) c on c.name = t.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=13a7ab1fbcff67f500e0c072b51ff7f4).
Results:

```
> NAME   | STATUS | FLAG
> :----- | :----- | :---
> John   | N      | S   
> John   | Y      | S   
> John   | N      | S   
> Walter | N      | N   
> Walter | N      | N   
> Walter | N      | N   
> Smith  | Y      | S   
> Smith  | N      | S   
> Karrie | Y      | Y   
> Karrie | Y      | Y
```

Comment: @aa_shi if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark at the left.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can do this without counting, just using `max()` and `min()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when max(status) over (partition by name) = min(status) over (partition by name)
             then status
             else 'S'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

This implements the following logic:

- If the statuses are the same for a name, assign that status.
- Otherwise, assign `'S'`.

This logic is a somewhat simpler way of expressing your conditions.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=65d511980dc9dd1c969110d75e61bf83) is a db<>fiddle.

I'm not sure if getting the rows in the specified order is part of the question  If so, you can add:

```
order by (case when flag = 'S' then 1 when flag = 'Y' then 2 else 3 end),
         name
```

Comment: Simpler: in the first branch of the **case** expression, **then status** will work just as well.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Good catch.  I like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a join on subquery with conditional aggregation

```
select a.name, a.status
    ,  case when  t.tot_status_n > 1 and  t.tot_status_y >= 1 then 'S'
            when  t.tot_status_n > 1 and  t.tot_status_y =0  then 'N'
            when t.tot_status_y > 1 then 'Y' 
            else '?' end flag
from table_a
INNER JOIN (
    select name
       , sum( case when status = N then 1  else 0 end) tot_status_n , 
       , sum( case when status = Y then 1  else 0 end) tot_status_y
    from table_a 
    group by name 
) t on a.name  = t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using twice `count()` as window analytic function :

```
with A( Name, Status ) as
(
 select 'John'  ,'N'  from dual union all
 select 'John'  ,'Y'  from dual union all
 select 'Smith' ,'N'  from dual union all
 select 'Karrie','Y'  from dual union all
 select 'Walter','N'  from dual union all
 select 'Smith' ,'Y'  from dual union all
 select 'Walter','N'  from dual union all
 select 'John'  ,'N'  from dual union all
 select 'Walter','N'  from dual union all
 select 'Karrie','Y'  from dual       
), A2 as
(
 select a.Name, a.status,
        count(*) over ( partition by Status, name order by name ) count1,
        count(*) over ( partition by name order by name ) count2       
   from A
)
select a.Name, a.Status, 
       case when count1 > count2 or count2 > count1 then 
      -- the above comparison is needed to make sure "Name" has multiple "N" or "S"
            'S'
       else
            status
       end as flag
  from A2 a
 order by decode(flag,'S',0,1), a.Name;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/EQFXKT14034)</kbd>